# Changing one Vuejs v-model value is changing all other values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, v-model

I have a `Nuxtjs/Vuejs` application within which I am creating multiple `Nodes`. These `Nodes` have the `Radio button` for which I have assigned `v-model`. However, when I change the value of one `Vuejs v-model` is affecting all other `Node Values`. Following is the code sample that I have created for the `Node`. The `ID` value is unique for each `Node`.

```
<template>
  <div ref="el">
    <div class="header">
      Node: {{ ID }}
    </div>
    <div>
        Syntax:
        <input
            id="identifierTypeURN"
            v-model="identifierSyntax"
            type="radio"
            value="URN"
            name="instanceIdentifierURN"
            @change="instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange('URN')"
        >
        <label for="identifierTypeURN">URN</label>
        <input
            id="identifierTypeWebURI"
            v-model="identifierSyntax"
            type="radio"
            value="WebURI"
            name="instanceIdentifierWebURI"
            @change="instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange('WebURI')"
        >
        <label for="identifierTypeWebURI">WebURI</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am aware that this is happening because I am using the same `v-model name` for all the `Nodes` so I changed to something like this. But still the issue persists:

```
<template>
    <div ref="el">
        <div class="header">
            Identifiers
            Node: {{ ID }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Syntax:
            <div v-for="node in allNodeInfo" :key="node.identifiersId">
            <div v-if="node.identifiersId === ID">
                <input
                id="identifierTypeURN"
                v-model="node.identifierSyntax"
                type="radio"
                value="URN"
                name="instanceIdentifierURN"
                @change="instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange('URN')"
                >
                <label for="identifierTypeURN">URN</label>
                <input
                id="identifierTypeWebURI"
                v-model="node.identifierSyntax"
                type="radio"
                value="WebURI"
                name="instanceIdentifierWebURI"
                @change="instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange('WebURI')"
                >
                <label for="identifierTypeWebURI">WebURI</label>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        ID: '',
        nodeId: '',
        eventCount: '',
        bizStep: '',
        allNodeInfo: [],
        instanceIdentifierSyntax: ''
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        const id = this.$el.parentElement.parentElement.id
        const data = this.$df.getNodeFromId(id.slice(5))
        this.ID = data.data.ID
        this.nodeId = data.data.nodeId
        this.allNodeInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.modules.ConfigureIdentifiersInfoStore.identifiersArray, null, 4))
        const identifiersNode = this.allNodeInfo.find(node => node.identifiersId === this.nodeId)
        this.instanceIdentifierSyntax = identifiersNode.identifierSyntax
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.allNodeInfo, null, 4))
      })
    },
    methods: {
      // On change of the IdentifierSyntax change, change the value in the respective node info
      instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange (syntaxValue) {
        // Change the value of the respective syntax within the Node information in IdentifiersNode array
        console.log(this.ID + " --- " + syntaxValue)
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
  
  <style>
  </style>
```

I know I am making some small mistake where I need to differentiate each `Nodes V-model` but nothing is clicking me. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your parent element so as to be in a better position to help?

Comment: Can you share any allNodeInfo data set example?

Comment: @jssDev There is the sample `[
    {
        "identifiersId": 1,
        "identifierSyntax": "URN",
        "identifierNodeId": 1,
        "name": "identifiersNode1"
    }
]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your `node` and your `v-model` also to your methods within this event.. like this, because for every loop in your `v-for` there will be a "new created node" which includes your `v-model` and than you can refer to this:

```
@change="instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange('URN', node, identifierSyntax)"
```

In your methods you just do everything based on your `node.identifierSyntax = HERE WHAT YOU WANT`..

Hopefully I understood the question correct and helped you out!

---

**EDIT:** (Standard procedure)

Normally it looks like this when you add a single "input" to your `v-for`.

*Template:*

```
<div v-for="node in inputs" :key="node.id">
  <input v-model="node.someDefinition" :value="node.someDefinition"/>
  <div @change="another_Function(node, someDefinition)></div>
</div>
<button @click="add_new_Input>ADD</button>
```

*Script:*

```
data() {
  return {
    id: 0,
    inputs: [{   //this is representing the first input when side will be loaded
      id: this.id,
      //your stuff in here as well
    }]
  }
}

methods: {
  add_new_Input() {
    this.inputs.push({
      id: this.id += 1
    })
  }
}
```

This should be enough.. So in your `template` you have a `v-for` where your are looping over an array (or something else but in my case it's an array) with all `inputs` - be aware every `input` of me gets an unique `ID` when it will be created or added.

Also you have - in my case here - an `input-tag` where you can get the `v-model` or set the `:value`. It's binded to my **`unique node`** which I have created in my `methods`.

If you pass your `@change` you also have to pass the current `node` and the `v-model` / `value` that the correct one will be changed.

Hopefully it now helps you out!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but I don't believe it is the issue with the `@change` function. This function kicks in only when I change the value but the problem is arising when I add the `Node` dynamically to my `Canvas`. When I add single `Node` everything works correctly because there is a single `V-model` however if I add one more `Node` then there will be multiple `V-model` with same name. Hence, the problem arises so I believe we need to change the `V-model` name itself or I need to use the `:value`. Can you please provide some solution?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a standard procedure. I'm not able to change it right now specific on your case. But I hope this will let you understand how it works normally and you can adapt it on your problem. 

Sometimes also the ```change event``` is not working out how it should, at least on me.